# Is it possible to access iphone notes, calendar in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to access notes and calendar using native iphone app. I want to know is it possible in new iphone os? Is there any public pi for that?

Comment: I find it fascinating that if you Google "ios calendar access" it takes you to Stack Overflow in stead of Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is the Event Kit API which is documented in T[he Event Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/prerelease/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

As far as I know you cannot access Notes.

> The Event Kit and Event Kit UI
>   frameworks together allow iOS
>   applications to access event
>   information from a user’s Calendar
>   database. You can fetch events based
>   on a date range or a unique
>   identifier, receive notifications when
>   event records change, and allow users
>   to create and edit events for any of
>   their calendars. Changes made to
>   events in a user’s Calendar database
>   with Event Kit are automatically
>   synced with the appropriate calendar
>   (CalDAV, Exchange, and so on). This
>   document describes Event Kit concepts
>   and common programming tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Notes are now synchronized to the main IMAP server mail account. So if you can access that somehow then you could access the notes, potentially. However I think you'd probably have to link in your own IMAP client code, and ask the user for their login credentials.