# How to integrate the iPhone Calendar SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, calendar

i am new to IOS development and  i want to implement the iPad Calendar SDK in my project. Is it possible to implement iPad Calendar SDK.

Thanks in Advance,
Magesh

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want. Do you want access to the events in the iPads calendar app? Do you want to program you own calendar app or at least have a custom calendar/date picker inside you own app?

Comment: Kai, i want to access to the events in the iPads calendar app so, the calendar would like to show Year, Month, Day, week wise calendar by tapping these buttons

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the calendar UI components as used by apple in the Calendar.app on iPhone & iPad the answer is sadly no.  They are, for reasons unknown to man or beast, private. :(  There are plentiful open source implementations, some of which can be found here:

[Cocoa Controls - Calendar Search](http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Calendar)

However I can't recommend one, as yet I've not found one simple and suitable for my needs. YMMV.  For information on accessing calendar events [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941719/is-it-possible-to-accessing-iphone-notes-calendar-in-ios) may help.

Comment: You may also find this SO question pertinent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941719/is-it-possible-to-accessing-iphone-notes-calendar-in-ios