# Creating events on iOS5 calendar from web app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I tried a bit of research, but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.
Is it possible to access the calendar on iPad/iPhone iOS5 from a web app? 
My goal would be adding an event to it, is that achievable? Opening a filestream is an option, in case this helps.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941719/is-it-possible-to-accessing-iphone-notes-calendar-in-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not available through a web app. The only thing you can do is include a date in the text within the web app. iOS will detect it as an event (if formatted correctly) and will give the user an option to create a calendar event when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Here on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825221/add-calendar-event-to-android-from-web-vcs-download?lq=1), the OP mentions he had no problems in adding a calendar event on iOS by means of an iCal file created on the fly.