# IOS get calendar events and emails for exchange 2003

Tags: ios, email, activesync, exchange-server-2003

I'm working on a app where one of it's functionalities is to get the user's calendar and emails from a exchange 2003 server (possibly upgraded to 2013 in the near future). I've been looking around and haven't found any way on how to set up an ActiveSync or build something to allow me to get the user's events and mails to incorporate in my app.

I've also heard it's not possible to use ActiveSync on the IOS because of Apple and Microsoft agreement doesn't allow use in 3rd party apps. Is this true? Is it possible to build some workaround or any library that already implements the ActiveSync protocol. I need some confirmation because this is one of the major requests of my client and I need to prove if it's possible or not.

Thanks in advance for any possible enlightenment.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveSync is a proprietary Microsoft protocol and you will have to [license it from them](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/IPLicensing/Programs/exchangeactivesyncprotocol.aspx) in order to implement it in your app. It will cost you money to do so. You could instead look at [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) (a SOAP API in front of Exchange) but support for that in Exchange 2003 was very limited, to my knowledge.

You don't need to implement ActiveSync in order to get access to the user's Calendar events, as that can be done locally with the [EventKit API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941719/is-it-possible-to-accessing-iphone-notes-calendar-in-ios).

I'm not aware of an iOS API that lets you access the mail items on the phone, but others might know of one.

Comment: Tks for the info. From what i've read EWS appeared with Exchange 2007. The license wouldn't be the problem because that would be the client's responsibility. I'm not sure EventKit API will help because that will access the device's event's not the user's Exchange account calendar.

Comment: EventKit will work if the user's calendar is connected to Exchange.

Comment: True. But it's not gonna be an acceptable option because this is a corporate app and it's supposed to have multiple users on the same device, discarding that option to us.